# How to deal with generated sources in maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a multi-module project

```
/my-project
    /api
    /service
    /clients
    /api-integration-tests
```

Here are profiles from the parent pom:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>build-app</id>
        <modules>
            <module>api</module>
            <module>service</module>
        </modules>
    <profile>
    <profile>
        <id>generate-clients</id>
        <modules>
            <module>clients</module>
        </modules>
    <profile>
    <profile>
        <id>run-integration-tests</id>
        <modules>
            <module>api-integration-tests</module>
        </modules>
    <profile>
</profiles>
```

`clients` is a module that generates an artifact (`my-app-clients`) based on swagger specification. In the other words, **`clients` modules puts `my-app-clients` generated dependency in the maven repository**.

`api-integration-tests` requires `my-app-clients` as a dependency:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.yuriiknowsjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-app-clients</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

To run integration tests now, I have to execute 3 commands:

```sh
# Build my app
mvn clean install -Pbuild-app

# Generate an artifact `my-app-clients`
mvn clean install -Pgenerate-clients

# Run tests
mvn clean verify -Prun-integration-tests
```

I would like to simplify it to 2 commands

```sh
# Build my app
mvn clean install -Pbuild-app

# Generate `my-app-clients` artifact and run tests
mvn clean verify -Pgenerate-clients,run-integration-tests
```

But when I try to execute for the first time (let's say I have emptied the local .m2 repository)

```
mvn clean verify -Pgenerate-clients,run-integration-tests
```

I face an error:
*Could not resolve dependencies for project edu.yuriiknowsjava:api-integration-tests:0.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find edu.yuriiknowsjava:my-app-clients:0.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT in ...*.

So my question is there a way to tell maven something like: *"Hey maven, don't you worry about `my-app-clients` artifact, it will be generated after executing `-Pgenerate-clients` profile"*

Comment: What is the reason for all the profiles? Why not just put the four modules in the parent POM and run the build?

Comment: @JFabianMeier, I use profiles for convenience. Anyway, in this case, it doesn't matter. I tried to put all of the modules in the parent POM, but the problem remains. I guess this happens because maven reactor doesn't know anything about `my-app-clients` and cannot figure out that this is a generated artifact and it will be available after building the `clients` module.

Comment: Modules via profiles is in general a bad idea (even it comes to release creation). So I strongly recommend NOT to do that. If clients contains generated code via swagger the module is not generated it's the code which is generated.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a *dirty workaround* to this problem - I added `dummy-client` module which serves the purposes of a placeholder.

The problem is the following: `api-integration-tests` module requires `my-app-clients` as a dependency, but we do not have such artifact in our multi-module project. **`my-app-clients` artifact will be generated after executing the `clients` module**.

So I created a dummy child module that has artifact id `my-app-clients` to keep maven reactor happy.

```
/my-project
    /api
    /service
    /clients
    /api-integration-tests
    /dummy-client # DUMMY!
```

And here is how dummy's pom looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
        <groupId>edu.yuriiknowsjava</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- This is the key element. We want to trick maven into thinking that this dummy is the missing dependency maven reactor wasn't able to resolve! -->
    <artifactId>my-app-clients</artifactId>

    <!-- We want to put explicit dependency, so that maven build clients and then - this dummy -->
    <modules>
        <module>../clients</module>
    </modules>

    <!-- This is a dummy to mock "my-app-clients" artifact to make maven reactor happy -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- We don't won't to install this dummy into the local repo -->
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then I had to modify `run-integration-tests` profile to include *my dummy module*.

```xml
<profile>
    <id>run-integration-tests</id>
    <modules>
        <module>dummy-client</module>
        <module>api-integration-tests</module>
    </modules>
<profile>
```

Now, when I execute

```sh
mvn clean verify -Pgenerate-clients,run-integration-tests
```

Maven reactor will build the project in the following order:

1. my-project (pom)
2. clients (jar)
3. my-app-clients (pom) # this is a dummy and this step doesn't publish anything
4. api-integration-tests

See [official documentation about maven reactor build order](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

**DISCLAIMER**: I don't think it is a good solution and I would not recommend using it for real-world projects. But I think it is good to know that such an option exists.